# ASP.NET Crystal Report, after exporting to PDF, Data vanishes

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I created a SAP crystal report(Crystal Report Version - 13.0.6) in my ASP.NET (.Net Framework 4.0) project. After generating report in Crystal Report Viewer it displays Data in it. But when I export it to PDF, data gets vanished and shows only labels and lines. I google a lot to find solution but I didn't get satisfactory solution for this problem. If any one knows solution then let me know.

Comment: How are you exporting it.

Comment: There is button of export on Crystal Report Viewer. After clicking and selecting the export to pdf option, it exports current report to pdf..

Comment: just out of curiousity can you trt exporting to some other format? preferable .rpt format and then check if the resulting file has data in it. It could possibly be something else and nothing to do with pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. Actually while exporting to PDF, there were not getting an IDs due to PostBack  event of page is true. So that DataSet couldn't get an IDs to retrieve data from Stored Procedure.